# a question regarding "as long as"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-usage, as

Sentence 1: I haven't known him as long as **you**.

Sentence 2: I haven't known him as long as  **you have known him**.

Sentence 3: I haven't known him as long as  **I have known you**.

Does the meaning of sentence 1 equal to sentence 2 or sentence 3?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 can be better expressed with a have at the end:

> I haven't known him as long as you **have**.

This sentence has essentially the same meaning as sentence 2:

> I haven't known him as long as you have known him.

However, sentence 3 has a slightly different meaning:

> I haven't known him as long as I have known you.

Consider that there are two people A and B, talking about C. In the first two sentences, B tells A that he/she hasn't known C as long as A has known C. However, in the third sentence, B says to A that he/she hasn't known C as long as he/she has known A. There's the difference.

Hope it's clear now!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, it can be (2) or (3).

Comment: Is the second "as" in "as long as" a proposition or conjunction?

Comment: It's an adverb used in comparisons.